# Call Childs Function From Parents Class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Hi I have 2 JS Class like below

```
class WPOnion_Field_API2 {
    constructor() {
        wp.hooks.addAction( 'wponion_reload_fields', this.init_fields );
    }

    js_settings(elem, _default) {
        return wponion.field_js_args( elem, _default );
    }

    is_valid() {
        return ( 1 >= this.elem );
    }

    init_fields() {
        console.log( 11111 );
    }
}
```

Extended Class

```
class WPOnion_Field_inputmas extends WPOnion_Field_API2 {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    init_fileds() {
        console.log( 1 );
    }
}

let WPOFInputMask = new WPOnion_Field_inputmas();
```

In the first class u can see i used the called `this.init_fields`
which means the class its extended with should call the childs function but its calling its own class's function.

Comment: `init_fields` is not the same as `init_fileds`. Spelling matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't *call* `this.init_fields` in the constructor of the base class. You only referenced it:

```
wp.hooks.addAction( 'wponion_reload_fields', this.init_fields );
```

To *call* it, you need to add parenthesis:

```
wp.hooks.addAction( 'wponion_reload_fields', this.init_fields() );
```

But, since it doesn't return anything, it wouldn't be correct to pass the result as an argument to `wp.hooks.addAction`.

And, in the base class, the method is called: `init_fields()`, but in the extended class it's called `init_fileds()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. and i realized  how stupid am i :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to call parent class's method from child class.

If yes, use `super.parentClassMethodName()` from child class if child class has also same name.

Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super